# Need to commit open transaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

Is it need to commit opened hibernate transaction.What will happen if someone didn't?
Is it caused to some issues?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Commit** will make the database commit. The changes to persistent object will be written to database. If you don't commit you will loose the changes you made in the database.

Answer (score 1):

A transaction MUST ends, either by a commit or by a rollback.

Why ?

A transaction is consuming resources:

- some bytes in memory
- usually a JBDC connection. (or any kind of connection to a transnational external resource)

So,  if a tx never ends : it will use a JDBC connection forever and there a good chances that you run out of database connections.

Conclusion : you don't need to commit every tx, but you need to terminate them : either by a commit or a rollback (there is no other end state for a tx)

Comment: in here, I mean we do not going to save or update with the db: just select the values from db.but for getting hibernate sessions we use an utility class's method.though we open a tx for that method we are not going to commit it when session is closed.

Comment: As soon as your tx is bound to the session (it's a frequent use case): closing the session will also release transactionnal resources.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is not only with hibernate transaction but with all database transactions. Commit/ Rollback are Atomicity of **ACID** *(Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability)* properties which actually represent/specifies TRANSACTION. Atomicity is more like do or die.

**Answer to your question:**

```
//creates something like cache/temporary space for you to perform all your operations. Note   this changes will not be reflected in your database at this point.
 Session.beginTransaction();

//perform some db operations 

//this line flushes/post your changes from temporary stuff to database. If your changes contains error then this will not be affected/made changes to the database else the changes will be affected.
Session.commit();
```

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

A transaction must be closed. So by committing the transaction would automatically be closed as long as current context property mentioned in hibernate.cfg.xml is is thread and not managed.
This is to maintain the ACID properties of transaction. Also a when a transaction is begin it is allocated a lot of memory and resources.
What the best practices suggest is you should roll back the entire transaction and close the session if there's exception in catch block and you should commit the transaction in the last part of try block rather than finally block.